# Confused on how to use user input from HTML in javascript file for GET request

Tags: javascript, html, express

I am trying to make a simple website that utilizes the google books API so users can search for books. I am starting the server using express in index.js in the root directory of the project and have my static files in a directory called public. In my index.html I have a form to collect user input and am not understanding how to use that input as a query parameter for my GET request in my index.js file. I am trying to create the GET request in the index.js file so that I can call it in my script.js file and parse the data there. I have the pieces but I don't know how to connect them all together.

form from index.html

```
   <form id="submit">
        <label for="query">Enter Book Query</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="query" placeholder="Search For Books!">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
```

from script.js

```
var submit = document.getElementById('submit')

submit.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    query = document.getElementById('query').value
})
```

from index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.static('public'))


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})

app.get('/search', async (req, res) => {
    const fetchApi = await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${query}`)
    const bookResponse = await fetchApi.json()
    return bookResponse
})
```

Comment: If you don't want to use normal form submission, you need to send an AJAX request. There are many tutorials on this.

Comment: You say, "...the GET request in the index.js file so that I can call it in my script.js...". You can't call the GET request in the *index.js* from *script.js*. —— *index.js* is executed on the server, and *script.js* is executed in the client browser. The only connection you have between the two is HTTP, which is a text string. Either submit the form to `/search`, which loads a new page. Or use [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to send a GET request to the server, without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `action` attribute to the html Form

```
<form id="submit" action="/search">
    <label for="query">Enter Book Query</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="query" placeholder="Search For Books!">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

so that tells the form, where to send the data.